# How to get information using jsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, tags, jsoup

I have this html

```
<td rowspan="3" class="event start"> <a href="/search/1065650;1/note">INFO1<br>DETAIL1 DETAIL2<br>INFO2</a> </td>
```

how can I get INFO1 and INFO2 using jsoup??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that :

```java
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements td=doc.select("td.event.start");
Elements a = td.first().getElementsByTag("a");
String [] words = a.text().split(" ");
System.out.println(words[0]+" "+words[3]);
```

Tested on:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<td rowspan="3" class="event start"> 
 <a href="/search/1065650;1/note">
  INFO1<br>DETAIL1 DETAIL2<br>INFO2
  </a> 
</td> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works. Just tested. Which version of Jsoup are you using ? The principle is to find td with css classes "event" and "start" then get child a text content which will be "INFO1 DETAIL1 DETAIL2 INFO2" and then to get first and last of these words. I will add my test file in my answer to check